# PHP mail function (sending to my own domain)

Tags: php, email

I am hosting a domain with go-daddy, but the email form I made will not send emails to any address hosted on the domain. Here is my php:

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['Name'];
 $email = $_POST['Email'];
 $subject = $_POST['Subject'];
 $message = $_POST['Message'];
 $headers = 'From: ' .$email;

 if ($name == null || $email == null || $subject == null || $message == null) {
echo '<br>';
echo '<center>Please fill all fields.</center>';
 } else {

 $mail = mail('<example@domain.com>', $subject, $name. ' says: ' .$message, $headers);
 if ($mail === true) {
 echo '<br>';
 echo '<center>Thanks for messaging ';
 echo 'example@domain.com';
 echo '. We will respond ASAP.</center>';
 } else {
 echo '<br>';
 echo '<center>Your message to: ';
 echo 'example@domain.com';
 echo ' could not be sent. Please try again later.</center>';
 }
 }

?>
```

If I set the email (first parameter) of the mail function to my gmail account, this works fine, but if I set it to any emails on my domain, it fails. When I first made the form, this code worked fine. I have not changed anything about it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is sounds like a DNS or server configuration issue to me. Basically if the mailboxes are hosted elsewhere, its possible that the machine on which your site is hosted is sending them into mailboxes local to the hosting machine instead. If you can get the maillogs you can try and confirm that the messages were sent, and if you have access to the system mail folders you could check to see if they contain your missing messages.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing to change in your code, mail function uses smtp settings in php configuration file (php.ini). check which server you are using from php.ini and see the mail server configuration. There might be restriction to send mails to some of domains.

Comment: If server running on unix/linux check the email server log under /var/log/maillog for the error.